# Linear System of equations - Correct solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

maybe someone can spend some minutes to check my solutions, preparing for an exam I dont have the solutions for the following one, but at the same time the odd solutions confuse me and make me think I might be wrong.

"A team of three workers has to finish a project. It would take one person to finish it in 18 months.
Person A is fully available, Person B has to spend 25% of the time on a different project, Person C will not be available for one month during this project.
How much time (partially/share) does each person has to spend on this project so it can be finished in 18 months total?"

My solution:

$$
\frac{x}{18} + \frac{y}{18} + \frac{z}{18} = 1
$$

$$
y = 0.75x
$$
$$
z = x-1
$$

$$
\frac{x}{18} + \frac{0.75x}{18} + \frac{x-1}{18} = 1
$$

$$
2.75x = 19
$$

$$
x = \frac{76}{11}
$$

$$
y = \frac{57}{11}
$$

$$
z = \frac{65}{11}
$$

Can this be correct? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It is quite correct.